# jQuery New Row Tables

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm having an issue in creating a new row in a table having got some data from a JSON API.

So my jQuery looks like:

```
for (var j=0; j<jsonData.reports[0].length; j++) {
     $('#failuresTable tbody #first').append("SOMETHING");
}
```

What this is doing is simply adding it all into one cell. What I want it to do is create a new row each time. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: post your HTML code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this...

```
 for (var j=0; j<jsonData.reports[0].length; j++) {
         $('#failuresTable tbody #first').append('<tr><td>SOMETHING</td></tr>');
    }
```